# Select Distinct Pairs from Two Lists of MySQL ids

Tags: mysql, select

I have two lists of ids from two different tables `(1,2,3)` and `(4,5,6)`

I want to run a `SELECT` query so that I end up with with the ids paired-off, with each id being used just once:

```
1,4
2,5
3,6
```

Is there a way to create this `SELECT` query?

**UPDATED, MORE INFO**

I have 3 database tables:

```
**user**
id
username

**prize**
id
description
expiration

**user_prize**
id
user_id
prize_id
```

I would like to take a specific set of `user.ids` (example: 1, 2, 3) and a specific set of `prize.ids` (example: 4, 5, 6) and insert them into the `user_prize` table. I do not care which of the selected `user.ids` are paired with which of the selected `prize.ids`.

Any advice about how to run this `INSERT` / `INSERT...SELECT` query would be appreciated.

Comment: These are single column values, not actual comma-separated lists in the columns right?  How do you decide which numbers are paired with which? Is it just by relative sort order? (that is, why is 1 paired to 4 rather than 1 to 6 for example)? Are they exactly the same length?

Comment: Yes, just comma separated values. I am going to spin this into an `INSERT...SELECT`, just need to insert these pairs into another table. Does not matter which value gets paired with which, just need one value from each set and each value can only be used once.

Comment: "_Yes, just comma separated values_" So you mean the table literally contains the value `1,2,3`, or the table contains a column with 3 rows having 3 values 1, 2, & 3?

Comment: Show us your db schema with real sample data. please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create unique indexes to enforce your constraint.

```
create unique index u_user_prize_prize_id on user_prize(prize_id);
create unique index u_user_prize_user_id on user_prize(user_id);
```

Then attempt your `INSERT ... SELECT` with `IGNORE`.

```
insert ignore into user_prize(user_id, prize_id)
select u.id, p.id from user u join prize p;
```

Thus, only 1 user and 1 prize pair would be inserted.

Comment: How you `JOIN`  without `ON` clause ?

Answer (score 0):

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c773/1)**

You use variables to create a `row_id`

```
INSERT INTO user_prize(`id`, `user_id`, `prize_id`)
SELECT U.rank as `id`, u.id as `user_id`, p.id as `prize_id`
FROM 
(
  SELECT u.*, 
       @r1 := @r1 + 1 AS rank
  FROM users u, 
       (SELECT @r1 := 0) r
) U
JOIN 
(
  SELECT p.*, 
       @r2 := @r2 + 1 AS rank
  FROM prize p, 
       (SELECT @r2 := 0) r
) P
ON U.rank = P.rank;
```

Comment: Be leery of using `@variables` as they may not always hold the value you expect. I used to be a fan of their potential power, but cannot condone their use due to the undefined behavior they can exhibit.

Comment: @JRD can you show me an example where you get an undefined behavior?

Comment: No example, and it may work for every case, but there is the possibility it will not work and depends if the risk is acceptable. _As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement._ ... _However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined._ [User Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)

Comment: @JRD Yes I read that, But without one example to compare is hard to see when is usuable or not.

Comment: The documentation says don't rely on it. So it is a matter of what risk is acceptable. It may depend on the requirements and constraints, but I would not build unnecessary risk into a system. How can you ever be sure that the results are correct, without verifying them? And if the results need to be verified apart from the method that got them, why not just use verification method in the first place.